# There is recursion error in SVM and GUI code I made

Tags: python, pyqt, svm, pyinstaller

I'm making GUI program with SVM algorithm using `pyqt`. There is `svm1()` in class of `pyqt`. I took the number of ql I need it and put it `self.param` and run the code.

I can run the code with Pycharm. But there is a recursion error when I make an `.exe` file with `pyinstaller`.

I found `sys.setrecursionlimit(5000)` and use it. But it didn't work. (I used 10^6 instead of 5000. But it didn't work.)

```
def svm1(self):
    tbl1 = pd.read_csv("A.csv")
    label1 = tbl1["label"]
    temp1 = tbl1["temp"]/ 50
    pressure1 = tbl1["pressure"]/ 8
    time1 = tbl1["time"]/13
    wh1 = pd.concat([temp1, pressure1, time1], axis=1)
    data_train1, data_test1, label_train1, label_test1 = train_test_split(wh1, label1)

    self.clf1 = svm.SVC()
    self.clf1.fit(data_train1, label_train1)

    raw = [self.param1/50, self.param2/8, self.param3/13]
    self.test1 = np.array(raw)
    self.test1 = self.test1.reshape(1, -1)
```

There is an error message:

```
RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded while calling a Python object
```

I guess there is something wrong in SVM code and GUI code. Is the problem using `self.` in every variable?

Comment: Can you put full error trackeback?

Comment: Have you tried creating a [example]?